# Catia Macro - select all ''non'' updated features

Tags: select, macros, feature-selection

I am trying to highlight or select features that non updated and create a macro (in catscript) that does it. I could than manually choose the ones that really does nothing and delete them. Can someone please help me.
Thank you

haven't tried anything yet...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.